# Armature deforming a mesh, weird banding appearing

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

my first attempt at rigging. I have a hand with bones, and posing is working, but I'm getting these 'bands' that appear in Solid, material and render. You can see them here at the base of the thumb.

[image]

I'm assuming it's an issue with the original mesh. Mesh was created with Skin modifier. It's not a normal face orientation as they are all the same.

Any advice, greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess it's caused by the weight painting. Your mesh is very high poly, does it need to?

Comment: Ah ok, I used automatic weights, so should I try to paint the weighting instead?
High poly was just because I was trying to make it smooth as possible. I might try to recreate it and keep the poly low, if you think that would help?

Comment: Keep your object as low-poly as possible, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier if you want to create virtual topology, and right click > Shade Smooth to make it look smoother, but don't work with so many polygons, it will make things very hard to work with  :/

Comment: ok great, thanks!